# How to find out ip address of AP im connected to? Not Router

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, scanner

I have just wired up the house and installed a trendnet tew-637ap (already had it). I had reset the AP to default. it also has an open wifi. I couldn't find the AP on the LAN table on the router (via mac address). so I connected to the AP. somehow its connected to the router but isn't listed on the LAN Table. I used Angry IP Scanner and pinged the broadcast IP address. they just listed what the router had. 
Its there and not there at the same time.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 right now.

Comment: sudodus, my question already says i checked the router.

Answer (score 1):

Your Trendnet WiFi AP should get an ip from your router dhcp on his ethernet adapter.

So if you want to know this ip address, check the dhcp server

But it seems that there is no web server on the Trendnet AP, configuration must be done with a setup utility you can find on the Trendnet support website : [Trendnet support for TEW-637AP](http://www.trendnet.com/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=155_TEW-637AP)